# Heroku Maintenance -- password authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I created a new postgres database on Heroku and within 1 hour Heroku sent me an email saying it was undergoing maintenance. Now I can't connect to my db at all.

```
(node:1857) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "uapwyccbzgnhuy"
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/adamkent/Dev/devmtn/wpx18/week5/node-3-lecture/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/adamkent/Dev/devmtn/wpx18/week5/node-3-lecture/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/adamkent/Dev/devmtn/wpx18/week5/node-3-lecture/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

I'm using SQL tabs to interface with my tables. I'm being prompted to add a password and when I add the password for my default user Heroku created it says password authentication failed. It worked until Heroku performed maintenance.

Comment: You commissioned a Heroku PostgreSQL addon. The password is in the environment variable for your database addon.

Comment: I have the same problem I created 3 times a new database and 3 times Heroku did maintenance and broke my app, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when they performed maintenance issues on my database. As a workaround, you can reset your password in account settings. Doing so resets the API key and other relevant credentials that you require to access the database.